# How does Anakin get his weapon back?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones, anakin-skywalker

When Anakin is on the conveyor belt his lightsaber is cut in half. When he’s fighting Count Dooku a little later he has it again. How did he get it?

Answer (score 23):

He was thrown a new lightsaber during the Geonosis arena fight by Jedi Knight [Sephjet Josall](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sephjet_Josall). Obi-Wan was thrown one by Jedi Knight [Nicanas Tassu](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Nicanas_Tassu).

[image: Gif showing the Jedi battling the droids in the arena, two Jedi named above unclip spare lightsabers and throw them to Obi-Wan and Anakin who are riding an animal with Padme between them]

> Mace winced when he spotted Obi-Wan, Anakin, and Padmé sent flying into the air by the terrified and bucking reek. He motioned to other Jedi, but needn’t have, for those closest were already rushing toward their vulnerable companions, throwing lightsabers to Anakin and Obi-Wan.
>
> When those two ignited their blades, Anakin’s green and Obi-Wan’s blue, and Padmé came up between them, a discarded blaster pistol in hand, Mace breathed a bit easier.
>
> <sub><sup>[Attack of the Clones: Official Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_II_Attack_of_the_Clones_(novelization))</sup></sub>

Comment: I've watched this frame-by-frame and I've come to the conclusion that Wookieepedia is wrong about which Jedi passed which Jedi their spare lightsaber.

Comment: Wait. The two closest? That would imply that most if not all Jedi were carrying spares, so that those who happen to end up closest to Anakin and Obi-Wan could give them their spares. Oh well, I guess the force willed it or something.

Comment: @bitmask I presumed those two were tasked with delivering the light sabers, which is why they were the closest. They just bolted there. Whills of the Force had nothing to do with it.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. I must have looked away for just a second. Luckily they were the right color. If they were tasked with getting them lightsabers how would they even know that they were lost in the first place?

Comment: @BJones knowing they were captured, it wasn't a stretch to make that presumption.